# Checking empty of EditText and send Toast - / avoid saving empty data to SQLite

Tags: android, android-edittext

Sorry taking your time, am asked a question in a very wrong way.

So what I doing now, a small notepad program where the title and content saved of the note to the SQLite database.

This part working as should, but I don't have any input check and the app saving the note with empty title and content.

there is my current code for this :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        dba = new DatabaseHandler(MainActivity.this);

        title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
        content = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.wishEditText);
        saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveToDB();
            }
        });

        }

    private void saveToDB() {

        MyNote wish = new MyNote();
        wish.setTitle(title.getText().toString().trim());
        wish.setContent(content.getText().toString().trim());

        dba.addWishes(wish);
        dba.close();
        //clear
        title.setText("");
        content.setText("");
         Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayNotesActivity.class);
         startActivity(i);

     How can I implement a basic input checking and avoid the saving of empty notes?
     my first idea was to check the emptiness of the input and drop a toast message, tried several solutions from not, but not worked me.
     many thanks
     C
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to be sure you're using the same EditText variable which in this case I think is title.

```
EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
if(title.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Input Text Is Empty.. Please Enter Some Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
                 else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, title.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }
               }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

U need to specyfi your question.
But from what i undestood u don't know how check editText is empty and don't know why can't write into text box.

First easy method is just check length of string if it bigger than 0 that's meen it's not empty

```
        EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.IDEDITTEXT);
        if(String.valueOf(title.getText()).length()>0){
            //do something
        }else{
            //do something
        }
```

And about second (i thing question) is check your xml file (layout) does your editText is enabled and not is textViev.

Btw your code is hard to read like your question:)

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.titleEditText);
if(title.getText().toString().length()<=0) {
           Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Input Text Is Empty.. Please Enter Some Text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }
else {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, title.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
   }
 });
```

try this code...